# Stlying Between Resolution

Tags: html, css, mobile, dynamic, resolution

Im doing some simple styling between different mobile devices and was wondering whats the best way to change depending on the resolution.

As my application looks fine on low resolution devices, but on high the fonts to small and other things are to small as well.

I was thinking of one style sheet depending on resolution but was wondering if this was the best way or is there better ways to implemented this situations.

The devices are all blackberry from new to old hence the high and low resolution.

Is there anyway even just to scale content up if the screens bigger?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) to target different screen sizes in CSS.

Here's a list for Blackberry devices http://responsive.co.za/blackberry-specific-media-queries/

Answer (score 2):

You can do all this using CSS3 media queries.

Here are some resources

- http://brendanmckenzie.com/2012/06/there-is-no-mobile-framework
- http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/
- http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile

Answer (score 1):

You should create media queries like they said but if you are doing this for a large number of devices and/or your css file becomes very long, I would do it with if then statements so that each device doesn't have to download a huge css file that contains all of the media queries for every device.